# Facebook login screen appears instead of friends list on AppRequest API call in Unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-share

I am trying to implement 'Invite Friends' feature in my unity app. As per docs I call 'FB.AppRequest' with valid parameters but when this API is executed it opens a dialog with Facebook login page instead of FB user's friends list and asks user to login even though the user is already logged in with facebook. Only after successful login in that dialog it shows friends list. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my code :-

```
FB.AppRequest(
    "App name",
    null, null, null, null, null, null,
    delegate (IAppRequestResult result) {
        Debug.Log(result.RawResult);
    }
);
```

[image: This screen appears on AppRequest API call]

Comment: do you mean "logged in with the facebook app"? because that is a different login than the one in the browser.

Comment: And a mere Webview component, what is likely what is used here in a unity environment, does not share any cookies with the “normal” browser on a mobile device either.

Comment: @luschn, the behaviour is the same even if logged in app or browser. It show the login screen like in the attached image.

Comment: @misorude, so if the normal browser is not aware of the logged in user and again asks for login than how do I solve it?

Comment: by letting the user log in again?

Comment: @luschn but that is bad user experience, no user would like to login again and might just close the dialog because its an extra effort.

Comment: it is neccessary though, there is no other way

Comment: @luschn, but there are other mobile games who have FB invite which does not ask for re-login.

Comment: native apps? unity apps? web apps? there are differences, you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199416/discussion-between-jay-mehta-and-luschn).

Comment: @JayMehta Did you find a solution to this problem?